# Datos vacios al enviar correo mediante formulario PHP

Tags: php, html, email, mail

Hice un formulario para que los datos lleguen a un correo en especifico, la página la tengo montada en HostGator, y si se envía el correo solo que los datos que deberían aparecer como el nombre, asunto, y mensaje, pero no aparece nada, espero me puedan ayudar. Esto es lo que me aparece en mi correo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código HTML:

```
<form action="formulario_contacta.php">
      <div class="campo">
          <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
          <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" required>
      </div>

      <div class="campo">
          <label for="email">E-Mail</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="tu@correo.com" required>
      </div>

      <div class="campo">
          <label for="Asunto">Asunto</label>
          <input type="text" name="asunto" id="asunto" placeholder="Escribe el asunto" required>
      </div>

      <div class="campo mensaje">
          <label for="mensaje">Mensaje</label>
          <textarea id="mensaje" name="mensaje" placeholder="Escribe un mensaje" required></textarea>
      </div>

      <div class="campo enviar">
          <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-primario">
      </div>
</form>
```

Código PHP:

```
<?php
$destino = "micorreo@gmail.com";
$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$asunto = $_POST["asunto"];
$mensaje = $_POST["mensaje"];

$contenido = "Nombre: " . $nombre .
             "\nCorreo: " . $email . 
             "\nMensaje: " . $mensaje;

$enviado = mail($destino,$asunto,$contenido);


if ($enviado)
header("Location:formulario_contacto.html");
else
    echo 'Error en el envío del email';
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que **no estás usando el método POST** y estás tratando de leer los datos en la superglobal $_POST, que se encuentra vacía.
La razón para que ocurra este fenómeno es que **el valor por defecto del atributo *method* para el elemento *form* es GET**.

> The method attribute's invalid value default and missing value default are both the GET state.

ver https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#attr-fs-method

La solución es asignarlo explícitamente así:

```
<form action="formulario_contacta.php" method="post">
<!-- sigue tu código -->
</form>
```

Nota: Cómo dices que el correo se envía no hice comentarios a tu php. Pero, noto que tratas de leer en $_POST sin asegurarte que las claves existan. Debes hacer algo como:

```
<?php
$variable = isset($_POST[$clave]) ? $_POST[$clave] : '';
// esto asegura asignación sin error.
// no entiendo por qué no se produjo error de lectura y se envió el correo.
// En el caso de tu código podría hacerse así:
$nombre = isset($_POST["nombre"]) ? $_POST["nombre"] : '';
$email = isset($_POST["email"]) ? $_POST["email"] : '';
$asunto = isset($_POST["asunto"]) ? $_POST["asunto"] : '';
$mensaje = isset($_POST["mensaje"]) ? $_POST["mensaje"] : '';
// sigue el resto del código.
```

Comment: Una duda probablemente un poco obvia pero yo lo desconozco, en la parte de PHP al momento de colocar `$variable  = isset($_POST[$clave]) ? $_POST[$clave] : '';` ¿se debe colocar en todas las variables ? ejemplo:  `$variable  = isset($_POST[$nombre]) ? $_POST[$nombre] : '';` y así sucesivamente con email y mensaje? y al final donde coloco mi variable `$variable`?

Comment: Si. pero voy a editar el código para que lo veas

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, me ha ayudado muchísimo  :)

Comment: Fue un gusto ayudar!!